# Objective-C code to generate a relative path given a file and a directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file

Given a file path and a directory path as `NSString`s, does anyone have Objective-C code to generate a path to the file, relative to the directory?

For example, given the directory `/tmp/foo` and the file `/tmp/bar/test.txt`, the code should produce `../bar/test.txt`.

I know Python, at least, has a method to do this: [`os.path.relpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath).

Comment: certainly we could all write one (or dig one up), but you're asking would send off bells.  you should try to use `NSFileManager`, especially on iOS.  Apple is in a long-term process of closing off the file system to the User, and in the process formalizing how the programmer should/can access something.  dot dot slashing your way around is a good way to run amok of their app - - - that said `[NSString pathComponents]` will help you decompose them and start from there

Comment: Warning noted. For my particular use case, I'm operating exclusively within my app's sandbox on iOS. I have a full path to a file which I need to pass to an API which assumes a path relative to a particular directory and will not accept full paths ([`imageNamed`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)). I realize I have the tools to craft this, but I expect someone has a well-debugged version in their toolkit which would be of general use to SO visitors. No sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: are you sure? i have a great 6-sided wheel for sale ;-)  - - - i'm sure you know the caveats that come with `imageNamed:` - - - it will hold a copy of the image data until the app quits, use only for small, frequently and always used images - - - if that's not the case use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`  - - - i would never use `imageNamed:` on something not in the app top level bundle or you end up with names with ..s in them …

Comment: That wheel would definitely be worth reinventing, or at least reimplementing :). My app requires at least iOS 4.2, so I get to enjoy all the bug fixes they've made to `imageNamed:`. It now has excellent caching behavior, which is why I want to use it instead of `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: I would be mildly surprised if somebody had a version of this they use all the time. It's just not that common a task in the typical use cases for Cocoa. Generally, either you've got a path from a user (in which case you know exactly what path you want), you derive the path from a system function (in which case you know exactly the path you want) or you have the path hard-coded into your application. It's quite unusual that you would need to derive a relative path from one arbitrary location to another arbitrary location.

Comment: have you tried sending a ../relative/path.jpg to `imageNamed:`? i'd be interested to confirm it even works.

Comment: Ironically, I've decided not to use `imageNamed:` after all. One of my uses for it was to cache generated thumbnails. Alas, there's no way to force invalidate the thumbnails when I need to regenerate them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rather than continue to defend why I need this, I decided to just write it and share. I based this off of an implementation of Python's `os.path.relpath` at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-August/1215220.html

```
@implementation NSString (Paths)

- (NSString*)stringWithPathRelativeTo:(NSString*)anchorPath {
    NSArray *pathComponents = [self pathComponents];
    NSArray *anchorComponents = [anchorPath pathComponents];

    NSInteger componentsInCommon = MIN([pathComponents count], [anchorComponents count]);
    for (NSInteger i = 0, n = componentsInCommon; i < n; i++) {
        if (![[pathComponents objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[anchorComponents objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            componentsInCommon = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfParentComponents = [anchorComponents count] - componentsInCommon;
    NSUInteger numberOfPathComponents = [pathComponents count] - componentsInCommon;

    NSMutableArray *relativeComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:
                                          numberOfParentComponents + numberOfPathComponents];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfParentComponents; i++) {
        [relativeComponents addObject:@".."];
    }
    [relativeComponents addObjectsFromArray:
     [pathComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(componentsInCommon, numberOfPathComponents)]];
    return [NSString pathWithComponents:relativeComponents];
}

@end
```

Note that there are some cases this won't correctly handle. It happens to handle all the cases I need. Here is the skimpy unit test I used to verify correctness:

```
@implementation NSStringPathsTests

- (void)testRelativePaths {
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"/a" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"/"], @"a", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a/b" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"a"], @"b", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a/b/c" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"a"], @"b/c", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a/b/c" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"a/b"], @"c", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a/b/c" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"a/d"], @"../b/c", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a/b/c" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"a/d/e"], @"../../b/c", @"");
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"/a/b/c" stringWithPathRelativeTo:@"/d/e/f"], @"../../../a/b/c", @"");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't just use the full path?  `imageNamed:` totally supports that.  The root is your app's main bundle.

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/Path/To/Some/File.png"];
```

Comment: `imageNamed:` only accepts paths relative to the root of the app's main bundle. I want to load an image from my app's cache directory, which is outside of the app bundle. I cannot reference the file with an absolute path (I've tried), but I can reference it with a relative path (I've tried). Thanks for trying to help me find a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift version of Hilton's code

```swift
extension String {
    var pathComponents: [String] {
        return (self as NSString).pathComponents
    }

    static func pathWithComponents(components: [String]) -> String {
        return NSString.pathWithComponents(components)
    }

    func stringWithPathRelativeTo(anchorPath: String) -> String {
        let pathComponents = self.pathComponents
        let anchorComponents = anchorPath.pathComponents

        var componentsInCommon = 0
        for (c1, c2) in zip(pathComponents, anchorComponents) {
            if c1 != c2 {
                break
            }
            componentsInCommon += 1
        }

        let numberOfParentComponents = anchorComponents.count - componentsInCommon
        let numberOfPathComponents = pathComponents.count - componentsInCommon

        var relativeComponents = [String]()
        relativeComponents.reserveCapacity(numberOfParentComponents + numberOfPathComponents)
        for _ in 0..<numberOfParentComponents {
            relativeComponents.append("..")
        }
        relativeComponents.appendContentsOf(pathComponents[componentsInCommon..<pathComponents.count])

        return String.pathWithComponents(relativeComponents)
    }
}
```