# how to run a command

Tags: ios, swift

I want to run a command in `Swift` using `Process`. This is my current code:

```
process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
process.arguments = ["symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"]
```

However, this executes the command as `sh symbolicatecrash crash.crash`. I want this command to be executed as `./symbolicatecrash crash.crash`. How can I achieve the same in Swift.

I tried the following code (which is a run time crash)

```
process.launchPath = ""
process.arguments = ["symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"]
```

Comment: More thanks ;-) and you could consider deleting the no longer required comments now. Have a great day. I hope to acquire the legendary badge today, and your 25 points make a good start into this day. Because of that, you also won in the GhostCat upvote lottery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: when you want to be in **full** control of the path to be used - simply specify an absolute path for example, like:

```
process.arguments = ["/usr/bin/symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"]
```

or where ever that script is located.

Beyond that: keep in mind that "./" as relative path *depends* on the context of your application.

In that sense: you could have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539273/objective-c-code-to-generate-a-relative-path-given-a-file-and-a-directory) to understand how to actually "implement" relative paths - to then use that knowledge to create an *absolute* path that matches the desired *relative* path yourself.

But given the comment, the most "simple" answers seems to be:

```
process.launchPath = "usr/bin/env" process.arguments = ["./symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"] i
```

Comment: It does not answer my question of having an ability of running as, "./symbolicatecrash"

Comment: Please also see a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068822/getting-runtime-error-in-symbolicating-crash-using-process-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment79102277_46068822

Comment: `process.launchPath = "usr/bin/env"
process.arguments = ["./symbolicatecrash", "crash.crash"]` is the right way to  run this. Since your answer closely matches, please update this, post which I can mark this as correct. It is important to do it this way because without providing `launchPath`, application would crash at run time.